# delegate deallocated during the operation

Tags: ios, memory-management, delegates, nsoperation, dealloc

I'm looking for a solution that solves the following problem:

I have a NSOperation which download the image in the background:

```
@protocol CoreImageDownloadingOperationDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void) handleResponse:(UIImage*) response;
-(void) handleException:(MobileServiceException*) exception;

@end

@interface CoreImageDownloadingOperation : NSOperation{
}

-(id) initWithDelegate:(id<CoreImageDownloadingOperationDelegate>)del andImageID: (NSString *) image;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <CoreImageDownloadingOperationDelegate> delegate;
```

When it's finish the downloading, calling the delegate method, to set the image to the imageView:

```
pragma mark - overridden from NSOperation
- (void) main {

    if (self.isCancelled)
        return;

    @autoreleasepool {

        @try {

            UIImage* image = [[CoreEnvironment sharedInstance] getImageFromServer: [imageID stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            if (self.isCancelled)
                return;

            if(delegate){
                [delegate handleResponse:image];
            }
            else
                NSLog(@"CachedImageView already deallocated");

        }@catch (NSException *exception) {

            TestLog(@"%@", exception.reason);

            if (self.isCancelled)
                return;

            if(delegate && [exception isKindOfClass:[MobileServiceException class]])
                [delegate handleException:(MobileServiceException*)exception];

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: when I go to another page while the image is downloading, the cachedImageView is deallocated, but when the imageDownloadingOperation finishes downloading, the delegate is not nil, and it's trying to handleResponse... And of course I get message sent to deallocated...

I alloc init the operation like this in the CachedImageView:

```
CoreImageDownloadingOperation* imageDownloadingOperation = [[CoreImageDownloadingOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:self andImageID:imageKey];
```

[image]
or:

[image]

```
-[CachedImageView isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x18868550
```

Comment: replace assign property with weak

Comment: I'm not using ARC, so I can't use weak

Comment: There are a lot of frameworks that can load images in async way. SDWebImage for example.

Comment: weak and assign are the same, use weak for ARC projects but they amount to the same. Where is your Protocol declaration ?

Comment: I updated my question with the protocol declaration

Comment: Your declaration is wrong. You are missing the <NSObject> see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your protocol declaration? I'd expect to see this:

```
@protocol CoreImageDownloadingOperationDelegate <NSObject> 

- (void) handleResponse:(UIImage *) image;

@end

@interface CoreImageDownloadingOperation : NSOperation{
}

-(id) initWithDelegate:(id<CoreImageDownloadingOperationDelegate>)del andImageID: (NSString *) image;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <CoreImageDownloadingOperationDelegate> delegate;
```

You are getting the warning/crash because it can't find the responder `handleResponse:`

Also when invoking the delegate your better off doing:

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleResponse:)])
    [self.delegate handleResponse:image];
```

You don't need to check `if (self.delegate && [self.delegate responds ....` as it will return nil if the delegate is nil && if the selector is not implemented.

EDIT ***

Where you create:

```
CoreImageDownloadingOperation* imageDownloadingOperation = [[CoreImageDownloadingOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:self andImageID:imageKey];
```

I suspect this is being released, turn this into a property of the class it's in. Then try again (make sure to release it when you're done though) i.e

In your .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CoreImageDownloadingOperation* imageDownloadingOperation;
```

Then initialise with:

```
if (!self.imageDownloadingOperation)
    self.imageDownloadingOperation = [[CoreImageDownloadingOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:self andImageID:imageKey];
```

Comment: I'm making the same like this. The problem is after the image view deallocated, the delegate is still not nil, and operation trying to call the handleResponse method, and I get message sent to deallocated

Comment: That's not why it's crashing, if the delegate is not nil but there is nothing to respond to the selector it won't enter that if. There's something else at play.

Comment: I updated my code with <NSObject>. But it's still crash if imageView is dealloc, and the image didn t downloading. I updated my question

Comment: Thank you. it s helped for me

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is: when I go to another page while the image is
>   downloading, the cachedImageView is deallocated

The usual way to deal with this is to remove itself as a delegate in the dealloc of CachedImageView. Like

```
// in CachedImageView
- (void)dealloc {
  // CachedImageView keeps a reference to the operation
  // called imageDownloadingOperation
  imageDownloadingOperation.delegate = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way of writing the code is :

```
 if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleResponse:)){
    [self.delegate handleResponse:image];
}
```

This will avoid your crash.

Comment: This isn't solved my problem. It's crashes at respondsToSelector. See the picture above

Comment: see the one posting above.. you have to set the delegate to nil in the dealloc method first. Otherwise the app will crash, no matter what you are checking.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, I used CW0007007 solution and my own solution. So I turned my operation into a retained property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CoreImageDownloadingOperation* imageDownloadingOperation;
```

after this I checked if the operation is still alive

```
if (!imageDownloadingOperation)
        imageDownloadingOperation = [[CoreImageDownloadingOperation alloc] initWithDelegate:self andImageID:imageKey];
```

then added to the operation queue.

In the dealloc set the delegate to nil ( ofc only if the operation is alive ), and release it:

```
if (imageDownloadingOperation) {
    imageDownloadingOperation.delegate = nil;
    [imageDownloadingOperation release];
}
```

in the operation: ( and now if the imageView deallocated, its delegate will be nil, and won't crash anytime )

```
if (delegate)        
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(handleResponse:)])
        [delegate handleResponse:image];
```

Comment: This is basically what I said, mark my answer as correct if it helped you.